# Visuaizar PDF guardado en storage

Tags: laravel, pdf

Estoy intentando visualizar un archivo guardado en la carpeta storage sin éxito.

Actualmente soy capaz de visualizar imágenes

Controlador:

```
public function getImage($filename) {

    $file = Storage::disk('users')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

Planilla blade:

```
<img src="{{ route('occli',['filename'=>$viaje->oc_cli]) }}" class="image"/>
```

He encontrado el siguiente código para cargar archivos pdf:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="{{ route('occli',['filename'=>$viaje->oc_cli]) }}" width="100%" height="500" style="height: 85vh;">No Support</object>
```

Pero cuando intento cargar un .pdf guardado en la carpeta storage aparece un error. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado el problema modificando el código el controlador por:

```
public function getOccli($filename) {


    $file = Storage::disk('users')->get($filename);
    return  Response($file, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta de @Xavier Villafaina es buena y aceptable pero que pasa si los archivos esta subdividido en diferente carpeta, en el siguiente ejemplo le doy una idea:

- **users/reporte1/archivo.pdf**
- **users/reporte1/respuesta/archivoRespuesta.pdf**
- **users/reporte1/respuesta/proceso/estado/porcesoFinal.pdf**

en la url le va a pedir un solo dato en la cual va a genera un error CodeStatu 404

se puede soluciona usando parámetros de URL el siguiente método:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/FilesStorage/users/Descagar?extension=pdf%20&url=1-BOX-DE%2FImage.pdf

según el ejemplo del link tenemos un dato llamado

URL:  1-BOX-DE/Image.png

extension: pdf

en el archivo **web.php** definido la siguiente lineal

```
Route::get('FilesStorage/{disk}/Descagar','FilesStorageController@Descagar');
```

y en el controlador **FilesStorageController**  definimos la siguiente funcion, en caso de que sea un PDF o Imágenes me lo Visualice en el navegador, en caso contrario lo descargue.

```
public function Descagar(Request $request, $disk){
        $extension = $request->get('extension');
        $archivo = explode('/', $request->get("url"));
        $nombreArchivo = end($archivo);
        if ($extension == 'pdf') {
            return  Response(
                Storage::disk($disk)->get($request->get("url")),
                200,
                ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $nombreArchivo . '"']
            );
        }
        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png') {
            return  Response(
                Storage::disk($disk)->get($request->get("url")),
                200,
                ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $nombreArchivo . '"']
            );
        }
        return Storage::disk($disk)->download($request->get("url"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trata de reemplazar el valor de `data` de tu etiqueta `<object>` de la siguiente forma:

`data="{{ asset('storage/users/'.$viaje->oc_cli) }}"`

Ó de la siguiente forma si tus rutas de archivos públicos requieren de la palabra "public"

`data="{{ asset('public/storage/users/'.$viaje->oc_cli) }}"`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error.  Con el siguiente codigo consigo que se habra el pdf, pero me muestra solo texto con simbolos raros <a href="{{ route('occli',['filename'=> $viaje->oc_cli]) }}"><img src='{{ asset('img/document.png') }}'/></a>

Comment: Si descargas manualmente desde los archivos de tu servidor el archivo PDF que quieres abrir y lo abres manualmente en tu navegador, ¿te lo abre bien?

Comment: no he configurado la opción de descargarlo, pero si que puedo arribo desde la carpeta storage de destino cuando lo guardo así que no esta corrupto.